# How to fix update Modal not showing this.state.value

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am trying to create a modal that handles updates, but it's not showing {this. state. value}

```
state={
  name: '',
  businessName: '',
 
   show: false,
}

 
   showModal(e) {
        if (e) {
            this.setState({ show: true });
        }
    }

    showEditModal(e) {
  const { user } = this.props.auth;
        const email=user.email
        axios.get(`/api/v1/auth/userdetails/${email}`)
        .then(
          (res) => {    
         console.log(res.data) // res.data actually has data from API
          let user = res.data
          this.setState ({
   id:user.id,
    name:user.name,
  businessName:user.businessName,
 

          })
                this.setState({
                    show: true,
        });
        console.log(this.state.name) // i get undefined
            },
            (err) => {
                alert('An error occured! Try refreshing the page.', err);
            }
        );
    }



    onChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    };

    onSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const {
            _id,
          name,
  businessName,
 
    } = this.state;
    
        const userDetail = {
            _id,
          name,
  businessName,

        };

        console.log(userDetail);
        axios.post(`/api/v1/auth/update/${_id}`, userDetail).then(
            (res) => {
                Swal.fire({
        title: 'Profile ',
        text: 'Update successful!',
        icon: 'success',
        confirmButtonText: 'Ok'
      })
            },
            (err) => {
                alert('An error occured! Try submitting the form again.', err);
            }
        );
    };

    hideModal = () => {
        this.setState({
            show: false,
    name:'',
  businessName:'',
 
        });
    };

ModalForm=()=>{
        
return <div style={{ backgroundColor: 'white' }}>
                                <Modal
                                    {...this.props}
                                    show={this.state.show}
                                    onHide={this.hideModal}
                                    dialogClassName='custom-modal'
                                >
                                    <Modal.Header closeButton>
                                        <Modal.Title
                                            id='contained-modal-title-lg '
                                            className='text-center'
                                        >
                                            Update Profile
                                        </Modal.Title>
                                    </Modal.Header>
                                    <Modal.Body className='modal-contentx'>
                                        <Form horizontal onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                                            <FormGroup controlId='formHorizontalEmail'>
                                                <Col smOffset={4} sm={6}>
                                                    <FormControl
                                                        type='Text'
                                                        backgroundColor='grey'
                                                        placeholder='name'
                                                        name='name'
                                                        value={this.state.name}
                                                        onChange={this.onChange}
                                                    />
                                                </Col>
                                            </FormGroup>
                                            <FormGroup controlId='formHorizontalPassword'>
                                                <Col smOffset={4} sm={6}>
                                                    <FormControl
                                                        type='text'
                                                        placeholder=''
                                                         name='businessName'
                                                        value={this.state.businessName}
                                                        onChange={this.onChange}
                                                    />
                                                </Col>
                                            </FormGroup>
                                            <FormGroup>
                                                <Col smOffset={5} sm={6}>
                                                    <Button type='submit' bsStyle='primary'>
                                                        Add
                                                    </Button>
                                                </Col>
                                            </FormGroup>
                                        </Form>
                                    </Modal.Body>
                                </Modal>
                            </div>

<ButtonGroup>
                  <Button className="btn-fill" color="primary" type="submit">
                    Save
                  </Button>
                  <Button className="btn-fill" onClick={(e) => this.showEditModal(e)}>
                  Update
                  </Button>
                 
              </ButtonGroup>

}

render(){
 return (
<div>
// Add form  is placed here
</div>
<div>
// modal form is placed here
{this.ModalForm()}
</div>
           )
}
```

the modal comes up onClick, but fails to show any value. When i do console.log(this.state.name) for instance i get undefined?!

I need the Modal to be populated with the value from the state. The response object from the console contains the data that i am using to update the state through setState().

i guess something is off though, but cant figure it out